# Javascript: How to implement iterator over multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, iterator, closures

I have 2 dim array, which looks like this:

```
var a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
```

I want to write an iterator which will return one value a time when it's called.

```
iterator(); //returns 1
iterator(); //returns 2
iterator(); //returns 3
```

I tried such approach:

```
function iterator() {
    var a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
    var i, j;
    return function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            var b = a[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                return a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
};
var a = iterator();
a(); //1
a(); //1
a(); //1
```

It always returns me first element.

I can try this one:

```
function iterator() {
    var a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
    var i = 0, j = 0;
    return function() {
        for (; i < a.length; i++) {
            var b = a[i];
            for (; j < b.length; j++) {
                return a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Also not works.

But if I try this one:

```
function test() {
    var a = [1,2,3,4,5], i = 0;
    return function() {
        while (i < a.length) {
            return a[i++];
        }
    }
}
var a = test();
a(); //1
a(); //2
a(); //3
```

It works fine.

What is the difference here? How to make for loop work?

One other visible problem for me is bounds. How should I stop when I reach array bounds?

Comment: you initialize `i=0 , j=0` with the for loop each time you call the function..

Comment: @Hacketo made an edit, check my second try for iterator. also won't work.

Comment: because you never increment i and j, it execute the return statement before

Comment: why don't you just collapse the array?

Comment: @epascarello I'm using it as 2d structure, to fill grid.

Comment: @Hacketo but how to increase `i` and `j` with for loop and keep them at closure? I stick to those ones because of bounds.

Comment: so the result is exactly the same.

Comment: @epascarello looks like you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an inner for-loop for the second dimension you can use a simple `if` to test the bounds of `j`

```
function iterator() {
    var a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
    var i = 0, j = 0;
    return function() {
        for (; i < a.length; i++) {
            var b = a[i];
            if (j < b.length){
                return a[i][j++];
            }
            j = 0;
        }
        return undefined; // reached when there is no value left
    }
};
```

Comment: Actually the loops are not necessary. You could just return a[i][j] or undefined.

Comment: @AdrianMaire the for-loop is only here to simplify the bounds check of `i` and `i` incrementation (save one line .) And I added `return undefined` because OP might want to return something else than `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not a good idea to extend standard feature, but for a didactical example I will make an exception. For real use, I suggest to implement your own class.

**General Idea**

```
Array.prototype.beginIterator = function()
{
    var counter = 0;
    return function()
        { 
            if (counter<=this.length) return this[counter++]; 
            else return undefined;
        };
}
```

*Then you could iterate like follow:*

```
var a = [3,1,4,1,5];
var it = a.beginIterator();
for (var i=it(); i!=undefined; i=it())
{
    alert(i);
}
```

This at the moment work only with single-dimension array, but it could be applied with any logic to other arrays or object.

**Multi-dimensional (Any) solution:**

The following iterator allow any-dimension array in any combination:

```
Array.prototype.beginIterator = function()
{
    var counter = 0;
    var iterators = null;

    return function()
        { 
            val = undefined;
            if (iterators!=null)
            {
                val = iterators();
                if (val!==undefined) return val;
                else
                {
                    iterators = null;
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            while (counter <=this.length)
            {
                if (!(this[counter] instanceof Array)) return this[counter++];
                else
                {
                    iterators = this[counter++].beginIterator();
                    val = iterators();
                    if (val!==undefined) return val;
                }
            }
            return undefiend;
        };
}
```

*Example of use:*

```
var a = [3,[3,5,7],4,[1,[2,5,8]],5];
var it = a.beginIterator();
for (var i=it(); i!=undefined; i=it())
{
    alert(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a loop at all in this case. You are effectively flattening the array anyway. You could just increment the indices along with a bounds check:

```js
function iterator() {
    var a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], i = 0, j = 0;
    return function() {
        if (j >= a[i].length) { j = 0; i++; }
        if (i >= a.length) { j = 0; i = 0; }
        snippet.log( a[i][j++] );
    }
};
var x = iterator();
x(); x(); x(); x(); x(); x(); x(); x(); x(); x(); 
x(); x(); x(); x(); x(); x(); x(); x(); x(); x();
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```